# Error when trying to create Heroku app on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heroku

When I try to do `heroku create` I get the following error message:

```
d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:83:in 'read': No such file or directory -d (Errno::ENOENT)  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:83:in 'extract_help'  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:51:in 'method_added'  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/lib/heroku/command/addons.rb:14  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'gem_original_require'  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:17:in 'load'  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:16:in 'each'  
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:17:in 'load'    
from d:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.0.1/bin/heroku:13
from d:/Ruby187/bin/heroku:19:in 'load'  
from d:/Ruby187/bin/heroku:19
```

This was trying to do the command in the Git Bash.  I get the same error message when I do `heroku list` or any other heroku command.

I also get an identical error message when I do the command in cmd, but the "-d" is replaced with a " - D"

The offending lines it references seem to be mentioning loading all the files from the "commands" folder.

The problems seems to be something with trying to access D as a directory instead of a drive, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I should try to fix this?

Extra info: I installed Ruby via the RubyInstaller.  I installed heroku via `gem install heroku`.  I'm running Windows 7 with Windows installed on my C: drive, but Ruby and everything is installed on my D: drive.

Comment: I used to do Rails development on Windows, and then I finally moved off of Windows so I could do Rails development properly.  My recommendation is that if you want to keep using Windows OS for other legitimate purposes, run Linux in a virtual machine, and do your Rails development there.  Don't use Cygwin -- it's way slow for Rails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Explanation** :
I had the same problem when deploying on Win7 to Heroku.  It seemed that almost any heroku command threw a similar exception.  All of my code was on the C drive, so your multiple drives aren't the root of the problem.  I dug a bit deep into the heroku gem and determined that this is a bug within the gem: there are two methods of handling the parsing paths-one which works and one that doesn't.

**Solution** :
Heroku gem is broken on win7 machines and you can find my fix [here](http://github.com/belkin/heroku).

I'll be submitting this and will update when it's available in the actual gem.  I hope this solves your problem.

**Update** :
Submitted the ticket last night, [heroku ticket 106](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/106#comment_1068744).  I did get a reply from someone using 1.8.7 that says it's [still not working](https://github.com/belkin/heroku/commit/8b2da8b2566fb70861480da32d23c2030a55d2ce#commitcomment-360547) as it did for me, still looking into it and will keep updating here.

**Update 2** :
The fork has been pulled into heroku client 2.0.3 and some additional updates to this issue in 2.0.4 which have [closed ticket 106](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/106#comment_1068744).

**Solution Summary** :
gem install heroku -v=2.0.4

Comment: +1 for excellent behaviour - just spotted you opened an [issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/106) against the original gem too :)

Comment: Thanks, still trying to iron out the full issue but glad this worked for you.