# Heroku on windows - 'no such file or directory'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've followed the Heroku installation instruction on windows, have git working from the ruby command line (path env variable set), but each time i try to run a basic heroku create command, i get the following error:

```
c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.0.2/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:83in 'read': No such file or directory - C (Errno:ENOENT)
```

I've added my executable directory to the path environment variable (c:\ruby192\bin) which was the guidance from rooting round stackoverflow, but this didnt seem to help.

Any thoughts? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes looks like a very similar error - I followed that URL to learn of the need to add the path variables, which i did but alas no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the same thing yesterday. It was an issue with *Heroku gem 2.0.2*.

this thread helped me solve the issue [Error when trying to create Heroku app on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811703/error-when-trying-to-create-heroku-app-on-windows).

I did: **gem install heroku 2.0.4** to **heroku keys:add** to **heroku create**, and everything worked as it should.

It was a bug with *version 2.0.2* i believe, Heroku *2.0.4* should work.

Comment: Found the same issue, once upgraded to the 2.0.4 gem it all worked as normal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.
1. go to c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.0.2/lib/heroku/command/base.rb file
2. find the code for the 'method_added' method. there would be a line like this.

```
help = extract_help(*(caller.first.split(":")[0..1]))
```

replace the above line of code with the below code segment.

```
parts = caller.first.split(":")
line = parts.pop
until line.to_i.to_s == line
  line = parts.pop
end
file = parts.join(":")
help = extract_help(file, line)
```

I found this code segment from the method definition written just above the 'method_added'.

Comment: Interestingly, i ran gem heroku update which installed version 2.0.4 and everything worked fine. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I still occasionally have this problem (heroku 2.35.0 / Windows 7).  It comes up when I try to use heroku from the (convenient!) Git Bash shell that came with my git installation.  If I use Windows' own shell ("Command Prompt"), heroku runs fine.

I'm not sure what's going on; usually whatever it is heroku can't find works just fine if I type it at the next prompt.  Something must get messed up when Git Bash tries to set the PATH variable for the environment it's launching heroku in.