# Heroku on Windows: No such file or directory - C:\Users\田中/.heroku (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: heroku

Following [Heroku's indications](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/windows), I installed [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) on Windows.

Everything worked fine, including the `gem install heroku` command, but the next step fails:

```
$ heroku list
<enter credentials>
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod': No such file or directory - C:\Users\田中/.heroku (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I tried both from RailsInstaller's *Command Prompt with Ruby on Rails* and *Git bash* consoles, same result.

To try the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812047/heroku-on-windows-no-such-file-or-directory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811703/error-when-trying-to-create-heroku-app-on-windows), I typed `gem install heroku -v=2.0.4` and it installed fine, but still same problem.

The error appears just after I enter the credentials. If I enter wrong credentials, another error message is shown.

What is going wrong?
The directory `C:\Users\田中\.heroku` actually exists and is visible from the consoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the Heroku gem.

I have found a quick-and-dirty solution that works for me, here is the patch I wrote:
https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/heroku/commit/d45d2a9

After applying this fix, the commands go smooth and I am able to use Heroku+git normally.

Comment: UPDATE: My patch has just been merged into Heroku :-) https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/148